# django : makemigrations process does not end

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-1.11

when i run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` every thing is ok and changes are made but process does not end and I must press control+z to end process

why this happend??
is it normal?

db backend : mysql
python 2.7 
django 1.11
OS: ubuntu 16.04 TLS

EDIT: because threading I using threading and it make problem in migration and makemigration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.7 Migrations hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884573/django-1-7-migrations-hanging)

Comment: Have you searched Django's issues tracker ? And what db backend are you using ?

Comment: @McMuttob : no my django version is 1.11 and this problem is for PostgreSQL .  I use mysql .

Comment: and in this question he says (no failure, no success, just sits). my migrate is runnig well every thing is ok but just process does not end  but other thing like runserver is runnig well I dont have problem but  wonder why this is happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was, that I have started a thread from views.py. And this thread was running forever. Django could not end, inclusing the migration calls, until this thread was ended. Removing the thread solved the problem.